# Fix Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

What is a general solution to fix **`Uncaught ReferenceError`**.

I am creating a function to ensure debugging code goes into production. But there may be cases where a variable doesn't exist but the debugging code still exists. In such case it shouldn't halts the js.

```
function debug(data, type){
    if(type == 'alert' && mode !== 'production'){
      alert(data);
    }
    else if(type == 'halt' && mode !== 'production'){
      debugger;
    }
    else{
      console.debug(data);
    }
}

debug(xyz) //xyz doesn't exists
```

Comment: `debug(typeof xyz === "undefined" ? undefined : xyz);` maybe?

Comment: You could use a macr... oh, wait.

Comment: Why do you want to run your debugging code in production?

Comment: Where are you defining xyz ?

Comment: @lan isn't there no better way

Comment: @lexmihaylov it's just a example

Comment: Why would you pass a variable that doesn't exist to a function.

Comment: @WebDeveloper I don't think so. `typeof` is special in that it doesn't throw an error, while I'm pretty sure all other references to the variable would. I guess you could also use a `try`/`catch`

Comment: @Ian is there a way to suppress the error in the function call case . i can do this check inside the function

Comment: @WebDeveloper That's what I mean - I don't think so. If you try and reference a variable that isn't defined, you'll get an uncaught reference error. The way to check for existence is with `typeof`, otherwise you can't pass something that doesn't exist

Comment: No, because your function call expression includes an undeclared variable name, so there's no way to get the function to run to handle it. The execution engine will always choke on that before the function runs. You *must* handle it outside of the function; Ian's `typeof` code is a nice, concise way to do that, although more general solutions about handling debugging may be better in your particular case.

Comment: You could use devil's `eval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid running debug code in production.

Best is to have a build process that removes it, but a simple flag that wraps your debug calls works too.

```
window.DEBUG = true;

//...

if (DEBUG) {
    debug(xyz) //xyz doesn't exist... and it won't matter when DEBUG === false
}
```

This will be cleaner than testing for undeclared variables all over the place.

After all, part of debugging is finding accidental access to undeclared variables. So when debugging, we should want to see those ReferenceErrors so we can fix them.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
 if(Debug){
    debug(data,code)
 }
}
catch{
// swallow or do whatever you want
}
```